# Spring-Security-Facebook Plugin, Facebook login error

Tags: grails, facebook-login

I installed Spring-Security-Facebook Plugin in my app, and got the Login button in my login page.

When I am clicking on the login with Facebook button it is redirecting to facebook.com/login.php?api_key=....... and i am getting an error.

When I clicked on login with Facebook button in other websites it is redirecting to facebook.com/login.php?api_key........ and giving the login page.

I also tried the JavaScript code given in the Facebook Developers api in the page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/. Then also I got the same problem.

I don't know where i am going wrong. I think it is problem with the url redirecting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're using same site url as it configured in Facebook Developer Admin (something like `http://localhost:8080/my-app/`).

And also, if you setup Sandbox Mode (`Settings -> Advanced`), then Facebook will show you details of this error.